# simple image gallery - change image opacity via jquery?

Tags: jquery, gallery, thumbnails, opacity

I have done a very simple gallery using:

```
$('#thumbs img').click(function(){
$('#mainimg img').attr('src',$(this).attr('src').replace('thumb','large'));
});
```

what I would also like is for all the thumbnails to have their opacity lowered besides the first / starting thumb until clicked - at which point the starting thumb would have its opacity lowered and the clicked thumb would be fully viewable and so on...how easy is this to add to my current script?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need two images on top of each other for an effective fade, or else one just disappears before the other appears. You can do this by setting the current image as a background, then fade-in the image on top:

See: http://jsfiddle.net/Diodeus/gYyBL/ for an example.

Comment: sorry maybe i need to describe better i dont want the images to appear like that - nice example though. I want just my thumbnail images to have an opacity of say 60% besides the default / starting thumbnail which would be 100%. Then when the next thumbnail is clicked the first thumbnail joins the others in being 60% and the newly clicked thumbnail goes to 100%

Comment: It all comes down to using this:  $(this).fadeTo('',.01) where the opacity varies between 0 and 1 (1=100%)

Comment: so adding $(this).fadeTo('',1); brings the current thumbnail to the correct opacity but how do i make it "lose" the fadeto when another is clicked? thank you so much for your help!